# Woocommerce REST API - how to upload product attribute term thumbnail image

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Does anybody know how to upload product attribute term thumbnail image through Woocommerce REST API? I am in a very similar situation as shown in the following picture:

[image: woocommerce attribute thumbnail]

[image: attribute term detail]

I want to programmatically upload thumbnails of colors. I can not find any documentation. I tried this PHP code, but no succes:

```
$woocomerceClient->put('products/attributes/123/terms/456', ['featured_media' => 789]);
```

I have installed WooCommerce Product Search. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.